# SonataAdminBundle dump template variable

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata

I tried dump  variables in block template (block_core_children_pages.html.twig) by `{{ dump() }}` but it turn into blank page. Anybody have same problem? and I have some questions also:

1. How to pass a variable from  function: `{{ sonata_page_render_container('footer', 'global' ) }}` to template ?
2. What are variables is passed by default to block template?

Thanksss alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sonata_page_render_container` function takes the following arguments:

`public function renderContainer($name, $page = null, array $options = array())`

So you have the third argument to specify some options/settings to add to your block, like this:

`{{ sonata_page_render_container('footer', 'global', {mysetting: myvalue}) }}`

After that, you can modify your execute() BlockService's method to use the settings you passed.